# How to set default input source in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: defaults, input-source

I use two keyboard layouts (input sources) in my everyday work - the standard US and Russian-PC. In System Preferences/Language & Text/Input Sources I have activated the "Allow different input source for each document" option. Incidentally, I also have English as the top language in System Pereferences/Language & Text/Languages, even though that is not relevant to this particular problem. I also have Input Menu enabled at login window and experience no problems with that.

However, when launching a new window or application, I can never be sure what language I will start typing in. That's very inconvenient, especially in full-screen apps/windows/modes. I have been unable to determine a consistent pattern of when and why the input source changes or whether it even consistently "sticks" to the an application or window.

Extensive googling and searching through existing q&a here yielded no satisfactory answers. Most confuse the question with the language selection. I have once stumbled on a tip saying that if you press-and-hold the input source switch keyboard shortcut (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> in my case), you will get a visual switch cue (which is true), and that the default will "stick" to the value at which you release the keys (which I couldn't prove is working, at least for me, also default for what? current window?)

So the question is - how do I set a systemwide default input source, which will be applied to every new invoked application and its windows?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, don't you want 'Use the same one in all documents'? Then you get a default and can just change the input source when you need something different. (This, I guess, works best if you are mostly using one input source.)

Comment: That conflicts with my understanding of these two options. AFAIK, if I switch to "use the same in all documents", then a language toggled, say, in a browser window will carry over to a Terminal window I just switched from, causing me to try and type shell commands in Cyrillic when I switch back. So - no, I don't want same one in all documents. I want different input sources possible in different documents, but I want all documents to **start** from a default one which I can specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked Seth from CNET about this, and he replied me [this article (*Managing input methods in OS X*](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57453176-263/managing-input-methods-in-os-x/), I'm reading it, wish it will help us!! I use Sougou Input, Chinese Traditional, English and Deutsch, this whole changing game makes me crazy!!

Answer (score 9):

To expand on Han's answer, here is the excerpt from the article [Managing input methods in OS X](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57453176-263/managing-input-methods-in-os-x/)

> To change your default input method in OS X and avoid having to make
>   these adjustments for each application and document you open, you
>   first have to be sure the setting to allow a different input source
>   for each document is disabled. **To do this, go to the Input Sources
>   system preferences and select the option to "Use the same one in all
>   documents." With this setting in place, go to the input menu and
>   select the desired method you would like to have as your primary input
>   source.** After this is done, you can go back to allowing a different
>   input source for each document, and any newly opened documents and
>   applications will now use the desired primary input method, until you
>   manually change it for that document.